# NSURLSessionDataTask and threading

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I’m getting a JSON feed with NSURLSessionDataTask and populating an NSMutableArray that is inside a shared store which is a singleton. The NSMutableArray is accessible to the outside world through a getter that casts it as an NSArray.

The getter calls a refresh method which polls the JSON feed and populates the NSMutableArray, like so:

```
- (NSArray *)articles
{

    if ([_articles count] == 0) {

        [self refreshArticles];

    }
    return _articles;
}
```

Here’s some of that method:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:feedURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:4.0];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

                                                 if (!error && response != nil) {

                                                     // decode JSON and add resultant objects to _articles

                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                         NSLog(@"Updated feed");
                                                         [nc postNotificationName:@"MLNArticleStoreFeedDidUpdate" object:self];
                                                     });
                                                 } else if (response == nil) {
                                                     NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
                                                     [nc postNotificationName:@"MLNNetworkError" object:self];
                                                 }

                                             }];

[task resume];
```

This works, but every time the getter is called, the feed gets refreshed 7 times. I think this has to do with the getter's if clause continuing to be true while the feed downloads. I have mitigated this with `dispatch_once`, and it works but I feel like that's not right.

Here’s what the code is now:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)articles
{

    if ([_articles count] == 0) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            [self refreshArticles];
        });
    }
    return _articles;
}
```

But what I *mean* is: "if there are no articles, go get some, and ***then*** return". Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_once`, used in this way, will not do what you are trying to do. The real thing here is that you almost certainly **don't** want to wait for the network activity before returning. If you block the main thread like that, the OS will kill your app.

```
- (NSArray *)articles
{    
    if ([_articles count] == 0) {
        [self refreshArticlesFromNetwork];
    }
    return _articles;
}

- (void)refreshArticlesFromNetwork
{
    if (self.networkRefreshInProgress)
        return;

    self.networkRefreshInProgress = YES;
    [self showNetworkLoadingUI];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:feedURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:4.0];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSMutableArray* localArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        if (!error && response != nil) {
            // decode JSON and add resultant objects to local array
            [localArray addObject: ... ];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _articles = [localArray copy];
            self.networkRefreshInProgress = NO;
            [self hideNetworkLoadingUI];
            NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            if (!error && response != nil) {
                [nc postNotificationName:@"MLNArticleStoreFeedDidUpdate" object:self];
            } else if (response == nil) {
                [nc postNotificationName:@"MLNNetworkError" object:self];
            }
            NSLog(@"Updated feed");
        });
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

The key takeaways here:

- Show some "Loading..." UI to the user instead of blocking the main thread.
- Don't trigger additional updates if an equivalent update is already in progress.
- Don't modify model state used to populate UI from background threads.

Comment: Thanks! In other words, use a boolean flag to change to an "updating" state?

Comment: I’ve implemented this and it works like a charm. I already had the loading UI but the boolean flag together with a temporary NSMutableArray are brilliant. Thanks a million.